# setting default page for all folders with no index

Tags: php, .htaccess

is there any way to set a default page for all folders on server that don't have an index file?

Like a general 404 page?

The idea is to prevent browsing through folders with no index file

Can this be achieved with .htaccess or php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put

```
ErrorDocument 404 /path/to/file/that/handles/404/errors.php
```

in your httpd.conf

However, if you're wanting to prevent folder browsing, this won't help. You'll have to disable folder browsing in the first place:

```
Options -Indexes
```

Comment: Could you enlighten me on the `Options -Indexes` part? I've had to create the httpd.conf.

Comment: You could go look at the Apache manual. It's all online at http://httpd.apache.org. This is a help site, not a "please read the manual for me" site. In otherwise, "RTFM"

Comment: Thanks for the link and humour, added `Options -Indexes` to .htaccess works fine.